# Aliased Git Commands: '.;' did not match any files

Tags: git, alias

I am trying to create an alias to pull without having to commit first. I first tried this:

```
git config --global alias.pulluc 'git add .; git stash; git pull; git stash pop; git reset;
```

When running `git pulluc`, I then got complaints about `'git' is not a git command`. I changed it to:

```
git config --global alias.pulluc 'add .; stash; pull; stash pop; reset;
```

Now when I run `git pulluc` I get `fatal pathspec: '.;' did not match any files`

How can I include `git add .` in a list of commands in an alias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `git-config(1)` man page:

> If the alias expansion is prefixed with an exclamation point, it will
>   be treated as a shell command...

Since you're attempting to create an alias for a small shell script (a sequence of commands separated by `;`), you need to prefix the alias with an exclamation point.

Comment: I'm still unsure how to string the commands together though. `git config --global alias.pulluc '!git add .; !git stash; (etc)'` doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: The `!` only goes at the beginning of the expansion.  It's a marker that means, "the rest of this string is a shell script". So, `git config alias.pulluc '!git add .;git stash; ...'`

Comment: Ah, so only the first command in the list has an exclamation point before it. This did the trick: `git config --global alias.pulluc '!git add .; git stash; git pull; git stash pop; git reset;`